# ROS package not found after catkin_make

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, github, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello :)

I'm quite new to ROS and tried to install a package (laser_line_extraction) from github.
I completely followed this instruction https://wiki.nps.edu/display/RC/Setting+up+a+ROS+package+from+Git step-by-step.
But after creating the package with catkin it's there as a directory but can't be found with "rospack find ...".

[rospack] Error: package 'laser_line_extraction' not found

Online I found something about "sourcing the launchfile" but no explanation on what this means or how to do it.

Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354877/ros-package-not-found-after-catkin_make/) by [creazy](https://answers.ros.org/users/55782/creazy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the package was compiled successfully, try “source ~/.bashrc" or "source /path-ws/devel/setup.bash" and then "rospack find" again

---

Originally posted by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) with karma: 137 on 2020-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [creazy](https://answers.ros.org/users/55782/creazy/) on 2020-06-15**:
Thanks, it's working now! :)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-07-09**:
@creazy If this answer solved your problem then please mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark that's to the left of the answer